# angular2 primeng fileupload issue

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

I am using `ngprime fileupload` from [here](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload) to upload file and send it to a `rest service` which validates `swagger json` and then save file content to db but facing issues while uploading file.

here is my **fileupload.html**

```
<div class="ui-g">
 <p-growl [value]="msgs"></p-growl>
 <form [formGroup]="uploadForm" novalidate>
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <div class="ui-grid-row">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-12" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!uploadForm.controls['activity'].valid && uploadForm.controls['activity'].touched}">
      <div class="ui-grid-col-2"><label>Product Name </label></div>
      <div class="ui-grid-col-8">
        <input class="inputtext" type="text" formControlName="activity" placeholder="Product Activity"/>
        <div *ngIf="uploadForm.controls['activity'].hasError('required') && uploadForm.controls['activity'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">You must enter Product Name.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12" >
  <p-fileUpload name="demo[]" url="{{uploadUrl}}" (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" accept=".json,.text,.yml" maxFileSize="1000000" [disabled]="!uploadForm.valid">
    <template pTemplate="content">
      <ul *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length">
        <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedFiles">{{file.name}} - {{file.size}} bytes</li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </p-fileUpload>
</div>
```

and [image: upload.html view]

I am getting ...
   `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/upload. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)` error. Actually the request not even going to my rest serevice which I am running locally ...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity uploadFile(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
   /swagger validation logic 
}
```

what's the issue in my code?

Comment: Basically file upload should be MultipartFile MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE

Comment: It worked for `Angular1.4` where I did same `http.post(url, file)` , is there anyway to upload json or text files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following REST endpoint that consume the file being uploaded and create JSON response

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity uploadFile(@RequestParam("myfile") MultipartFile file, String fileName) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
         /swagger validation logic  
      }
```

Here "myfile" refers to the name attribute given in  component.

Comment: I am using custom upload and my uploadHandler is getting called. But after that there is no error and it's not calling to my controller. I have no clue what's happening as it's not throwing any error in the UI code.

Comment: Its really difficult to answer based on the information you have provided. The problem can be anything. Just try on calling the endpoint using any REST Client and see if you can hit it. Or just upload section of code (the backend and forntend code)

Comment: I agree with you. I guess I have to ask in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am using Jersey and below is my working code for primeng file upload (angular 4)

## HTML Code

```
<div class="row header">
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <p>
  owner-shop-customization works!
  <p-fileUpload name="file" url="http://localhost:1006/jsflab/rest/OwnerMyShop/uploadShopLogo"></p-fileUpload>
</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

## TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FileUploadModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-owner-shop-customization',
  templateUrl: './owner-shop-customization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./owner-shop-customization.component.css']
})
export class OwnerShopCustomizationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

## Webservice

```
@POST
    @Path("/uploadShopLogo")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public Response uploadPdfFile(  @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                                    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) throws Exception
    {  
            String fileLocation = "C://" + fileMetaData.getFileName();  
                    //saving file  
            try {  
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));  
                int read = 0;  
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];  
                out = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));  
                while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {  
                    out.write(bytes, 0, read);  
                }  
                out.flush();  
                out.close();  
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
            String output = "File successfully uploaded to : " + fileLocation;  
            return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();  
        }
```

## web.xml

```
 <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>invoicegeneratorwebservice</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
       <init-param>  
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>  
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;  
     org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>  
</init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>
```

## pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
</dependency>
```